# Interactive PL/SQL script

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

How do I write a PL/SQL script that acceptsthe user input like in the following format?

1 : Output Customers

2 : Output Employees

3 : Output Transactions

Enter your option (1/2/3) :

Thanks,
Pradeep

Comment: are you sure this is possible? pl/sql is running on the db server, it has no interative statements. do you use oracle forms?

Comment: often times people mistakenly use "PL/SQL" to mean "SQL for Oracle" -- is that what you mean here?  As the other commenter stated, true PL/SQL (a procedural language for Oracle that runs in blocks on the database server without interaction) has no capability to prompt for user input.  What I assume you mean is a SQL*Plus script, for which see Sodved's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're running in sqlplus something like this

```
PROMPT 1 : Output Customers
PROMPT 2 : Output Employees
PROMPT 3 : Output Transactions
DEFINE option = &enter_your_option

BEGIN
    IF( '&option' = '1' )
    THEN
        ....
    ELSIF( '&option' = '2' )
    THEN
        ....
    ELSIF( '&option' = '3' )
    THEN
        ....
    ELSE
        RAISE error;
    END IF;
END;
```